# Linked tables vs json objects

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

So the question what is better to use a linked tables vs json objects in a mysql database for many to many relationship so for example you have a `user` table like this

```
 id
 name
 email
```

and `event` table:

```
 id
 name
 description
```

The question is if its better to add a extra text field toward the `user` table with `text` column where you store a json object where you put `event ids` in like this

`user` table:

```
id
name
email
json
```

with the json object looking something like this

```
{
   {event_id: 1},
   {event_id: 2},
   etc
}
```

or have a linked table with

```
id
event_id
user_id
```

assuming you have a many to many relationship where one user can register for multiple events and one event can have multiple users. where you also want to count how much users belong to 1 event and also wanna ask which one is optimal to use for querying and performances while doing this in laravel.

Comment: No variants - linked table only.

Comment: For sure linked table is a better idea than the JSON field(if we're talking about relational database). Many databases don't support natively indexing on JSON fields, so your queries will be really slow when you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked table has all the information

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM linked_table GROUP BY event_id WHERE event_id = 10
```

So you now have the number of users that belong to one event.

even with mysql 8 you have to put much more work and code to get information.

Edit:

besides json are slightly better that comma separated  field [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)